# When to use <> when initiating an ArrayList (or any other object)?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a question regarding the initiation of ArrayList in Java.

As far as I know I have to specify the type of my ArrayList when initialize it.
For example:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, when I want to write a code to return an ArrayList of List,
which is from the values of a map
 `Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<>();`
If I tried to use the following, error happens

```
return new ArrayList<>(map.values())
```

or

```
return new ArrayList<List<String>>(map.values())
```

Instead, I can only use the one, without the <>.

```
return new ArrayList(map.values())
```

Could anyone let me know when I should or should not use the <> when I initialize an ArrayList(or any other objects)?

The original code is as written below

```
    public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
        if (strs.length == 0) return new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List> res = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s : strs) {
            char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(charArray);
            String key = String.valueOf(charArray);
            if (!res.containsKey(key)) res.put(key, new ArrayList());
            res.get(key).add(s);
        }
        
        return new ArrayList<List<String>>(res.values());
    }
```

Comment: _always_, really.

Comment: `new ArrayList(map.values())` is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). That is, a type for which all further generic type-checking is disabled. Don't use it.

Comment: should be `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: Your HashMap's values are `List`, which is basically `List<Object>`. It could hold a String, an Integer and a StringBuilder for all we know. That's why trying to create a `List<String>` from those values doesn't work - they aren't necessarily all Strings. We can't be sure it does hold strings. Change the map definition to `Map<String, List<String>>`, then revert the return to `return new ArrayList<>(map.values());`

Comment: @Michael "which is basically `List<Object>`" please don't say things like this: it's entirely valid to use a `List<Object>`, and have heterogeneously-typed elements. The problem is that `List` *isn't* a `List<Object>`, it's not type checked, and the non-type checking is viral through its returned values. Saying "is basically" implies they are similar enough in function that it's OK to use either, which it's not.

Comment: "*Saying "is basically" implies it's the same*" Disagree

Comment: @Michael what do you mean then?

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
  ...
  Map<String, List> res = new HashMap<>();
  ...
  res.put(key, new ArrayList());
  ...
  return new ArrayList<List<String>>(res.values());
}
```

The problem here is that `res.values()` isn't a `Collection<List<String>>`, which is what would be required: it's a `Collection<List>`.

The elements of `res.values()` are *raw types*: you've used `List` without specifying the type parameters.

Raw types disable type checking, meaning you can end up putting things into collections with types you don't want.

Every time you use a generic type, make sure it has type parameters (or diamonds, if allowed:

```
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
  ...
  Map<String, List<String>> res = new HashMap<>();
  ...
  res.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
  ...
  return new ArrayList<>(res.values());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the type of map value is List , but you define the type of list value is string.

And suggest use guava Multimap instead of Map<String ,List>